# Nil data is passed from tableview detail disclosure with prepareForSegue

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I need to pass a string with prepareForSegue from a tableView disclosure link. Here is the prepareForSegue code I use. This is the code I found in several cases when other users needed to do the same thing, but in my case it doesn't work. Problem is with indexPathForSelectedRow() that is nil:

```
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if segue.identifier == "alertsDetail" {

        let detailAlertViewController = segue.destinationViewController as DetailAlertViewController
        println(alertTable.indexPathForSelectedRow()) // NIL
        if let indexPath = alertTable.indexPathForSelectedRow() {
            let entryToPass = unpublishedPhotosObjectId[indexPath.row]
            detailAlertViewController.entryId = entryToPass
        }
    }
}
```

I named the tableView "alertTable" and not self because the tableview is not a view controller, just a view.
In case needed, here is tableview code:

```
 @IBOutlet weak var alertTable: UITableView!
  /////////////TableView - START
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return unpublishedPhotos.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 170
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell! {
    tableView.separatorColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("adminAlertsCell") as? adminAlertsCell

    var data = unpublishedPhotos[indexPath.row].getData()
    let image = UIImage(data: data)
    cell!.myImageInCell.image = image
    return cell

}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    // Add access to cell
    let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as? adminAlertsCell



        tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
        println(cell!.banSwitch.on)

    }
}



/////////////TableView - END
```

Comment: Your delegate and datasource are hooked up since you're populating data into the table, but is your IBOutlet to the alertTable hooked up in the storyboard?

Comment: yes, it' properly hooked to the table... I get the proper auto complete on it

Comment: Getting the correct auto complete on it doesn't mean that it's necessarily hooked up. Add a println(alertTable) in your prepareForSegue to see what it gives.

Comment: UITableView: 0x7f9921992600; fram ....... all the code about the table. It's hooked.

Comment: Are you triggering the segue from a detail disclosure button?

Comment: yes I do it from a detail disclosure button

Comment: That doesn't select a row, so indexPathForSelectedRow should be nil

Comment: that should be it. So which method should I implement ? And should it do something particular ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71892/discussion-between-rdelmar-and-robert-brax).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make the segue from the controller instead of directly from the detail disclosure button. Implement the method, 
tableView:accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath: and call performSegueWithIdentifier:sender: from inside that method. Pass the in-depth as the sender argument so you have access to that in prepareForSegue,

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) { 
    let indexPath = sender as NSIndexPath
    if segue.identifier == "alertsDetail" {

        let detailAlertViewController = segue.destinationViewController as DetailAlertViewController
        let entryToPass = unpublishedPhotosObjectId[indexPath.row]
        detailAlertViewController.entryId = entryToPass
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, the key here was that detail disclosure, even if it performed segue correctly, was not considered a "select" of a cell, thus was not working. Implementing the method you suggested : tableView:accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath fixed that.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is stated in the comments to your question, and there are several solutions.  Perhaps the quickest since you only have one section,  is to assign the indexPath.row to the tag of the cell.  Then in your prepare for segue, the sender will be your cell.  You can get the value out of it.  So in your cellForRow method before your return your cell:

```
cell!.tag = indexPath.row
```

Then in your prepareForSegue:

```
let cell = sender as? adminAlertsCell
println(cell!.tag)
```

Here I am just printing it, but you can use it to pass the row.